# Enable Smart Array P400 HP Proliant DL 120 G7

Tags: raid, hp, hp-smart-array, bios

I have a HP ProLiant D7 120DL with a Smart Array P400. After doing BIOS *"Restore Default System Settings"* the Smart Array can't see the drives attached to it.

When starting the server, Smart Array checks for disks, but POST the message "No drives where found".

Is there any option on the BIOS to enable the Smart Array? I enabled SATA RAID Support from *"Advanced Options / SATA Controller Options / Embedded SATA Configuration"*, but still I can't see any other option from the BIOS menu.

BIOS is HP RBSU(Rom Based Setup Utility) Version 3.00

Comment: Are the disks HP disks or other?

Comment: @DaveM Seagate disks

Comment: Be prepared for the fact that the array controller may not recognize the disks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the Smart Array P400 was broken. I found another one in my company storage, changed it and magically the Bios recognised the new controller and all the drives. Tips: check for the LED lights in the back of the controller, if the Smart Array works they are all lighted up and green.

Answer (score 1):

You can run HP Service Pack for ProLiant (SPP) and run HP SUM(smart update manager) to check if you have all necessary for your SmartArray P400.
If you have it, reinstall it otherwise simply install what's needed... surely:
.HPE Array Configuration Utility (ACU) (for Managing your array)
.Systems Insight Manager(for Monitoring)
.HPE Array Diagnostic Utility (ADU)(In depth diagnostic and reporting utility for all Smart Array controllers)
.HPE Option ROM Configuration for Arrays (ORCA) (A simple method for managing logical drives during system power up by pressing F8 during POST
Allows the ability to create arrays, logical drives, and assign an online spare drive
Allows the ability to view and delete logical drives
Allows the ability to select the boot controller
For advanced array configurations use ACU)

SPP: https://techlibrary.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx?version=G7.1

Some Installation Instruction: https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/free-software/spp-g7.1

Hope this is helpful or gave you some new ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't use SPP I don't have the license. I tried ACU, but it can't see the hard drives, and can't access ORCA for the same reason (it appears when at least one hard disk is detected). I tried with the Smart Update Firmware DVD (offline mode), and it installed something, but still the Smart Array can't find the disks. Could be a good idea to try online mode?